# positioning and scaling on site

Tags: html, css

I want to 3 div's b in a row bot they are in column. I don't know why is this not working. I tried everything what i found i the internet but nothing works. rest of code is in the link https://mega.nz/file/aGhEDZ5L#XkUoQib_FFsqTraD5UrgjDVhBQ0IwWB0kHNVc3N11us

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
   <style>
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<main class="container2">
    <div class="div1">
        <img class="image1 line1" src="../img/business-meeting.png">
        <img class="image2 line1" src="../img/scrolling.png">
        <img class="image3 line1" src="../img/certificate.png">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <div><---------this div
            <p class="text3">
                <b>Spotkania jeden na jeden.<br>
                    Skupiam się tylko na Tobie.</b>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div><---------this div
            <p class="text4">
                <b>Dostajesz Inner Balance Bluetooth Sensor<br>
                    I aplikację do kontrolowania postępów</b>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div><---------this div
            <p class="text5">
                <b>Jestem certyfikowanym trenerem<br>
                    HeartMath Institute</b>
            </p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add css and do NOT link to download files!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your CSS is currently, but you could do

```
.div2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: sorry I added my css now in the link

Comment: You shouldn't link to external files in your question. Please post the relevant part of the CSS file, and mark this answer as useful if applying the changes I suggested fixes your problem.

Comment: I can't add revelant part of my css because i have too much code